# How do I simulate this simple quantum circuit in MATLAB?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, simulations, software

I want to simulate a circuit similar to the one below in MATLAB. If you have a state matrix describing the state of 3 qubits, I understand that you could apply a CNOT matrix tensored with and identity matrix to $\psi_{0} $ get $\psi_{1}$, but if you want to apply a controlled operation to the 1st and 3rd qubit to get $\psi_2$, how can you do this? It's like you need "remove" the information about the second qubit, apply a CNOT gate, and then somehow integrate the result back with the superposition of the second qubit... I do not understand how to do this.

In general if I have a superposition of N qubits, how do I apply a controlled operation on qubits i and j?

[image: Simple Quantum Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

I think this will answer your question. How does the CNOT between qubits one and three work?
$$\left|000\right\rangle \to \left|000\right\rangle$$
$$\left|001\right\rangle \to \left|001\right\rangle$$
$$\left|010\right\rangle \to \left|010\right\rangle$$
$$\left|011\right\rangle \to \left|011\right\rangle$$
$$\left|100\right\rangle \to \left|101\right\rangle$$
$$\left|101\right\rangle \to \left|100\right\rangle$$
$$\left|110\right\rangle \to \left|111\right\rangle$$
$$\left|111\right\rangle \to \left|110\right\rangle$$

So its matrix would look like:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: That's a good start. But what if you wanted to simulate a bigger circuit with say n input qubits. Is there a general form that could simplify and not need to write out a (2^n)x(2^n) matrix?

Comment: @Scott Let me answer your question with this, if there was an efficient way of simulating generic quantum states and their operators on a classical computer, then ...

Comment: @Scott Matlab has support for "sparse" matrices if many entries are zeros.

Comment: @Scott rob is right(actually many modern programming languages support sparse arrays, including Mathematica and Matlab). There are algorithms for sparse matrices, but even in that case you would need to specify $\mathcal O \left(2^n\right)$ elements for your matrices, which is still huge.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is $|\psi_{FINAL}\rangle = CNOT_{12} \cdot CNOT_{13} \cdot |\psi_{INITIAL}\rangle$
;
where $|\psi_{INITIAL}\rangle = |\psi\rangle \otimes |00\rangle$.

So this operation goes as follows:

- 1st) if $|\psi\rangle$ is in state $|1\rangle$, then perform NOT on the 3rd qubit ($|0\rangle$ goes to $|1\rangle$ in the 3rd position).
- 2nd) if $|\psi\rangle$ is in state $|1\rangle$, then perform NOT on the 2nd qubit ($|0\rangle$ goes to $|1\rangle$ in the 2nd position).

The matrix representation is:
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @ZeroTheHero dude, I get it; but the answer is actually the correct one. No need for the -1 vote just because it's not fancy. I was short of time at the moment. There. Now it's edited to look fancy.

Comment: Your answer is different from @Ali’s and much less detailed.  If there is an error with the other answer (or with yours) there is no way to track it down from your post.  Maybe you can expand your answer?  It could be the ordering of basis states is different between yours and Ali’s and both answers agree, but then why repeat another answer?